# Fatal Error Coming on my website

Tags: wordpress, hosting

recently we get done our Wordpress based website - maclinesme.com but suddenly below error start appearing and we do not have any clue how to resolve it.Requesting all experts here to guid how to resolve this error. Hosting is IIS server

> PHP Warning:  require_once(D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\maclinesme.com\httpdocs\wp-content\plugins\contact-form-7/settings.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\maclinesme.com\httpdocs\wp-content\plugins\contact-form-7\wp-contact-form-7.php on line 66
>   PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\maclinesme.com\httpdocs\wp-content\plugins\contact-form-7/settings.php' (include_path='.;.\includes;.\pear') in D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\maclinesme.com\httpdocs\wp-content\plugins\contact-form-7\wp-contact-form-7.php on line 66

Answer (score 0):

The error you get indicates that you clearly have a path and or configuration issues.

Once resolved, you can get your site working as expected.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply but earlier it was working fine so there is any chance that path change itself ???

Comment: No; path can't just change by itself. Let's troubleshoot. First, try removing the entire `contact-form-7` folder from the plugin directory so as to deactivate it. Does that change something?

Comment: Hi, yes I renamed contact7 folder and then new error start coming - PHP Warning:  require_once(D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\maclinesme.com\httpdocs/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-pages.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\maclinesme.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\default-widgets.php on line 11
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\maclinesme.com\httpdocs/wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-pages.php' (include_path='.;.\includes;.\pear') in D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\maclinesme.com\httpdocs\wp-includes\default-widgets.php on line 11

Comment: Okay. Now, you should backup your entire WordPress project onto a save location ***(don't forget to backup your database as well)***. Then, download and install a fresh copy of [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/download/). **PLEASE NOTE**: make use of your initial **`wp-config.php`** for that purpose so as not to have to actually re-install, but replacing ALL other files. Please report progress after that.

Comment: How far @adishjain?

Comment: Hi, I am sorry for not updating state but somehow my colleague developer fixed issue.